# Angular animation gets hidden behind the other elements

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Note: New to Angular Animations

I have the following angular animation which animates (move) the div from source to target coordinates.

**Issue 1:**
Somehow the animation is working but gets hidden when it goes out of the div space. What can be the issue ?

**Issue 2:** 
How to create the motion in a curvy manner. Currently the animation is straight movement. I want it to go in a curve manner.

**Issue 3:**
How to handle situation if the target is `position: fixed;`. When I scroll the page the animations for some items seems like if the target coordinates are somewhere else.

I created a demo. It works well in stackblitz [See Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hewxs) but not in my project.

```
   const animation = this.builder.build([
      animate(
        '700ms ease-out',
        style({
          transform: `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0)`,
        })
      ),
      animate(
        '700ms ease-out',
        style({
          transform: `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0) scale(0)`,
        })
      ),
    ]);
```

Comment: That's strange that's it's working in stackblitz but not in your project. Have you checked dependencies? Are you using Ivy?

Comment: I am using Angular 9

Comment: Try enabling Ivy in stackblitz